# Reactor.core.exceptions$reactiveexception: java.net.Unknownhostexception: Name does not resolve

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

We're having trouble with accessing the properties of our storage services. We're getting java.net.Unknownhostexception every time trying to reach the endpoints of services (this happened with fileShare, table, queue, and blob).

This is how I access the blob service client properties (the same for other services):

```
this.blobServiceClient = getContext().getClient().getBlobServiceClient(storageAccount);
this.blobServiceProperties = blobServiceClient.getProperties();
```

I did try an nslookup from the command line, the storage account endpoint seems to resolve just fine. The storage account we're having trouble with is the kind Standard General Purpose V2 (StorageV2) which does support 4 kinds of storage services but the exception was still thrown:

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: java.net.UnknownHostException: {redacted}.table.core.windows.net

    at reactor.core.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:396)

    at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:97)

    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1707)

    at com.azure.data.tables.TableServiceClient.getProperties(TableServiceClient.java:401)

    {redacted piece of stack trace}

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error

       at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99)

       ... 14 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: {redacted}.table.core.windows.net

    at java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:765)

    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1292)

    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1145)

    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1066)

    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$9.run(SocketUtils.java:169)

    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$9.run(SocketUtils.java:166)

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils.allAddressesByName(SocketUtils.java:166)

    at io.netty.resolver.DefaultNameResolver.doResolveAll(DefaultNameResolver.java:50)

    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolveAll(SimpleNameResolver.java:79)

    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolveAll(SimpleNameResolver.java:71)

    at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolveAll(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:73)

    at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolveAll(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:31)

    at io.netty.resolver.AbstractAddressResolver.resolveAll(AbstractAddressResolver.java:158)

    at reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector.doResolveAndConnect(TransportConnector.java:304)

    at reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector.lambda$connect$6(TransportConnector.java:127)

    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:125)

    at reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector$MonoChannelPromise._subscribe(TransportConnector.java:600)

    at reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector$MonoChannelPromise.lambda$subscribe$0(TransportConnector.java:520)

    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)

    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)

    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)

    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:403)

    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)

    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)

    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)

    ... 1 common frames omitted

    Suppressed: java.net.UnknownHostException: {redacted}.table.core.windows.net: Name does not resolve

       at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)

       at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:868)

       at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1303)

       at java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:816)

       ... 26 common frames omitted

    Suppressed: java.net.UnknownHostException: {redacted}.table.core.windows.net

       ... 27 common frames omitted

    Suppressed: java.net.UnknownHostException: {redacted}.table.core.windows.net

       ... 27 common frames omitted
```

**Sdks we're using:**

- azure-storage-blob: 12.19.1
- azure-storage-file-share: 12.15.1
- azure-storage-queue: 12.14.2
- azure-data-tables: 12.3.4
- azure-resourcemanager-storage: 2.25.0

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, @AlbertDao Can you share the code what you have tried?

Comment: @Venkatesan I would if I could but basically I was trying to grab the properties of the storage service of the storage account that I mentioned

Comment: Check whether your storage account is available in portal?

Comment: Yeah, it's available

Comment: Can you share information how you are accessing storage account properties?

Comment: I'm using azure sdk to get the blob service client from that storage account and get properties from it. That's where the exception is thrown

Comment: Please edit the question with your code what you have tried?

Comment: Also, Is there any firewall rule/network restriction?

Comment: No, I don't think there is any firewall rule or network restriction. I added the piece of code in the question

Answer (score 0):

To access the service properties of the storage account you can use the below Java code.

**Code:**

```
import com.azure.core.credential.TokenCredential;
import com.azure.core.http.policy.HttpLogDetailLevel;
import com.azure.core.management.AzureEnvironment;
import com.azure.identity.DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder;
import com.azure.resourcemanager.AzureResourceManager;
import com.azure.resourcemanager.storage.fluent.models.BlobServicePropertiesInner;
import com.azure.core.management.profile.AzureProfile;
import com.azure.core.http.rest.Response;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;

public final class App {

    public static boolean runSample(AzureResourceManager azureResourceManager) {
        Response<BlobServicePropertiesInner> response = azureResourceManager
                .storageAccounts()
                .manager()
                .serviceClient()
                .getBlobServices()
                .getServicePropertiesWithResponse("<Your-resource-group-name>", "<Your-storage-account-name>", com.azure.core.util.Context.NONE);

        if (response.getValue() != null) {
            BlobServicePropertiesInner properties = response.getValue();
            System.out.println("Blob service Id : " + properties.id());
            String jsonOutput = convertToJson(properties);
            System.out.println(jsonOutput);
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to retrieve BlobServiceProperties");
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static String convertToJson(BlobServicePropertiesInner properties) {
        try {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            return objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(properties);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "{}";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            final AzureProfile profile = new AzureProfile(AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
            final TokenCredential credential = new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder()
                    .authorityHost(profile.getEnvironment().getActiveDirectoryEndpoint())
                    .build();

            AzureResourceManager azureResourceManager = AzureResourceManager
                    .configure()
                    .withLogLevel(HttpLogDetailLevel.BASIC)
                    .authenticate(credential, profile)
                    .withSubscription("<Your subscription id>");

            System.out.println("Selected subscription: " + azureResourceManager.subscriptionId());

            runSample(azureResourceManager);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code retrieves the properties of **`Blob service`** (sample)  in an Azure Storage account. It uses the **`DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder`** to authenticate the user and obtain an access token and then uses the AzureResourceManager object to retrieve the BlobServicePropertiesInner object for the specified storage account. Finally, it converts the properties to JSON format and prints them to the console.

The above code accesses the blob service properties (the same for other services)

**Output:**

```
Selected subscription: xxx
default
Blob service Id : /subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/xxxx/blobServices/default
{
  "versioningEnabled" : true,
  "properties" : {
    "versioningEnabled" : true,
    "cors" : {
      "corsRules" : [ {
        "allowedOrigins" : [ "*" ],
        "allowedMethods" : [ "DELETE", "GET", "HEAD", "MERGE", "POST", "OPTIONS", "PUT", "PATCH" ],
        "maxAgeInSeconds" : 86400,
        "exposedHeaders" : [ "*" ],
        "allowedHeaders" : [ "*" ]
      }, {
        "allowedOrigins" : [ "http://www.contoso.com" ],
        "allowedMethods" : [ "DELETE", "GET", "HEAD", "MERGE", "POST", "PUT" ],
        "maxAgeInSeconds" : 86400,
        "exposedHeaders" : [ "*" ],
        "allowedHeaders" : [ "*" ]
      } ]
    },
    "defaultServiceVersion" : null,
    "deleteRetentionPolicy" : {
      "enabled" : false,
      "days" : null,
      "allowPermanentDelete" : false
    },
    "isVersioningEnabled" : true,
    "automaticSnapshotPolicyEnabled" : null,
    "changeFeed" : null,
    "restorePolicy" : null,
    "containerDeleteRetentionPolicy" : null,
    "lastAccessTimeTrackingPolicy" : null
  }
}
```

[image]

**Packages:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.azure.resourcemanager</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-resourcemanager</artifactId>
    <version>2.17.0</version>
</dependency> 
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.16.0</version>
 </dependency
```

**Reference:**

[Blob Services - Get Service Properties - REST API (Azure Storage Resource Provider) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/blob-services/get-service-properties?view=rest-storagerp-2023-01-01&tabs=Java#getblobservices)

Comment: Hi Venkatesan, thanks a lot for your detailed answer! The problem here is for other storage accounts, I can access their service properties without any issues. So my code shouldn't have any problems accessing the storage service properties of the storage account I'm talking about. I'm thinking that there is a way to change the endpoint of the service properties to a private one so when I try to access it using the regular format ({redacted}.table.core.windows.net), the exception is thrown. That's my thought but I'm not sure about what really happened